# How to send campaign to an individual using MailerLite API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, mailerlite

While using the MailerLite API, whenever I attempt to create a campaign and schedule it, it gets sent to all active subscribers. However, I want to send it to individual emails. Could you please tell me how I can send it to individual emails?

I tried to send an email to an individual email using the MailerLite API, but it's getting sent to all active subscribers. Additionally, there doesn't seem to be an option in the create campaign or schedule campaign API to add recipient emails.

Comment: Consider this workaround, before sending/creating the campaign consider creating/update a (new) group and add the individual to the designated group and use that group (with the sole subscriber) to send out the campaign